# About mysql compatibility in openGauss 3.1.0 ？

Tags: open-gauss

It is correct to execute the following three commands：

```
"alter database og_dolphin set enable_set_variable_b_format = on;";
"alter database og_dolphin set dolphin.lower_case_table_names = 0;";
"alter database og_dolphin set dolphin.B_COMPATIBILITY_MODE = on;";
```

But，an error occurred while executing the following two commands

```
"alter system set enable_dolphin_proto= on;";
ERROR: unrecognized configuration parameter "enable_dolphin_proto"
"alter system set dolphin_server_port=3307;";
ERROR: unrecognized configuration parameter "dolphin_server_port"
```

Comment: How is this question related to mysql? You cannot assume that two rdbms have the same set of configuration parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Since the following two parameters are added in openGauss 3.1.1, not in the openGauss 3.1.0 installation package